# Multiple minting on one TX

Tags: nft, mintingpolicy

I'm trying to mint a utility token and based on this quantity the investor will get different NFT bonus.

```
----------
mint :: MintParams -> Contract w FreeSchema Text ()
mint mp = do 
        let yacada          = Value.singleton yacadaSymbol yacadaName (calculateYacada $ mpAdaAmount mp)  
            yacadaNft       = Value.singleton yacadaNFTSymbol  "NFT" 1 --(giveReferalNFTN
            adas            = Ada.lovelaceValueOf $ mpAdaAmount mp            
            lookups         = Constraints.mintingPolicy policy <> Constraints.mintingPolicy levelPolicy
            destinations    = paymentTo mp
            payment         = Constraints.mustPayToPubKey (treasury destinations) adas
            mintYacada      = Constraints.mustMintValue yacada <> Constraints.mustMintValue yacadaNFT
            tx              = mintYacada
                                                             
        ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Void lookups tx
        void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx
        logInfo @String $ printf "------------------------------------------------------"
        logInfo @String $ printf "We forged y:%s NFT:%s" (show yacada)  (show yacadaNft)
        logInfo @String $ printf "------------------------------------------------------"

----------
```

The thing is that when I see the token in the wallet they both have the same policy :

(
Wallet 2:
{32d66bc1df769f6af0d37ccd9e3510ebf38b5e4c7235a2b2e4e9d08c, "NFT"}: 1
{32d66bc1df769f6af0d37ccd9e3510ebf38b5e4c7235a2b2e4e9d08c, "YACADA_TOKEN"}: 2000
{, ""}: 99697225
Wallet 1:
{32d66bc1df769f6af0d37ccd9e3510ebf38b5e4c7235a2b2e4e9d08c, "NFT"}: 1
{32d66bc1df769f6af0d37ccd9e3510ebf38b5e4c7235a2b2e4e9d08c, "YACADA_TOKEN"}: 1000
{, ""}: 99697137

Any ideas?
I have this "test code" on github if any needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my mistake. Just need to have the multiple policies in diferent files..